# How to fix date filter VBA as it is not picking up all dates that fall within my range

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula, date-range

I'm trying to create a filter that will filter out all dates that fall within the dates I choose. The dates I choose will always reflect a whole month.

For example, if I need data for May 2019, I will input my start date as 01/05/2019 and my end date as 31/05/2019.

My data filter will need to pick up all rows that go through my start date. So it should pick up whole calendar years (01/01/2019 - 31/12/2019), quarters (01/04/2019 - 30/06/2019) and any dates that cover the month of May.

Currently my filter only picks up whole calendar years and some (but not all)exact dates such as 01/05/2019 - 31/05/2019. So I'm missing a lot of information such as the dates that fall as quarters, or over a number of months surrounding May.

I've attempted to play around with the way that it filters by moving around the less than and more than sign but this just meant that a lot of the deals became excluded.

I use this filter on another workbook with much less data and it picks up all data. Whereas on this workbook, there is much more data and the start dates vary a lot, so I lose about half the data I need.

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
    lngStart = Range("AI1").Value 'this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("AI2").Value 'this is the end date

    Range("G2:G5000").AutoFilter field:=7, _ 'this is the start date column
        Criteria1:="<=" & lngEnd, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd

    Range("H2:H5000").AutoFilter field:=8, _ 'this is the end date column
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:=">=" & lngStart


End Sub
```

I would like all my data that passes through May 2019 (example month) to show when I click on my filter. It is only showing one of the month deals, and one of the quarter deals when there are five more.

Comment: Are all of your dates whole-numbers?  Because, 1-minute-past-midnight on the 31st May is *not* `<="2019-05-31"`:  Try using `<"2019-06-01"` instead?

Comment: How about showing some of your data (in text form that can be copied/pasted), that demonstrates the problem. In posting as text, consider using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question.

Comment: @Chronocidal I tried that but it came up with the same result. If it is of any use when I click into the filter on the header for 'Start Date' and 'End date' it starts of n chronological order by calender year. So 2018 (with an option to expand by month), same for 2019, 2020, 2021 etc. Then it goes to individual dates, for example 01/01/2019, 01/01/2018 etc

Comment: Just noticed, but why are you changing the range that your Autofilter applies to each time?  And why are you doubling your criteria?   `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Autofilter field:=7, criteria1:="<=" & lngEnd: ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Autofilter field:=8, criteria1:=">=" & lngStart`

Comment: @Chronocidal The way that data I use has been set up, the Start Dates and End Dates are in two separate columns. I had to double the criteria to filter each column. Otherwise it excludes lots of info

Comment: @RonRosenfeld could you recommend a site to upload on? I'd only be able to load the Start Dates and End Dates of my data as the rest is sensitive information. It seems like my filter only picks up dates that fall into calender years in the filter. Any dates that don't expand in the filter are ignored

Comment: People use OneDrive, Dropbox, and there are others.

Comment: @user11497252 I think you misunderstand:  You have written `Range("G2:G5000").AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="<=" & lngEnd, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd`, but that is functionally identical to just writing `Range("G2:G5000").AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="<=" & lngEnd`, because both of your criteria are the same

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhWQxWkebu6sgUe2jfqqCfNjMdp3)

Comment: @Chronocidal Ah sorry! I did misunderstand. It was duplicated because this has been the first time I've worked with the filter macro so I just did trial and error to get it to work how I wanted it to - I'm still quite new to vba. I amended it so it's not duplicated and it's still coming up with the same result (half the data missing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates are tricky in VBA filters.  For one thing, the VBA Date data type is not quite the same as an Excel value formatted as a date.

And I think your logic was a bit off also.

This seems to work on your sample data.

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long, fltrRng As Range
    lngStart = Range("J1").Value 'this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("J2").Value 'this is the end date
    Set fltrRng = Range("A2:H5000")


    With fltrRng
        .AutoFilter field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(lngStart)

        .AutoFilter field:=8, _
       Criteria1:="<" & CDbl(lngEnd)
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that we defined the entire filter range, but I would define it differently, and dynamically, so as not to encompass more rows than necessary.

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set fltrRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
End With
```

Also, we converted the `lngStart` and `lngEnd` to the Double data type, which is how dates are stored in Excel on the worksheet.  You could have just declared them as being of type Double.  So, with all that:

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim lngStart As Double, lngEnd As Double, fltrRng As Range
    lngStart = Range("J1").Value 'this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("J2").Value 'this is the end date

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set fltrRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With fltrRng
        .AutoFilter field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart

        .AutoFilter field:=8, _
       Criteria1:="<" & lngEnd
    End With

End Sub
```

Finally, the logic should state, I believe, that you want dates where

- the start column is equal or greater than the start date **AND**
- the end column is less than the end date (which, you have entered as one date past the actual desired end date, which is proper.

**EDIT:**

Another problem is that some of your dates are not "real Excel dates". In other words, they are textual representations of dates in a format that is different from your regional windows settings, where the Month entry is > 12.

This problem usually arises when a text or csv file is OPEN'd, rather than IMPORT'd, and the date format in the file is different from the date format in the Windows Regional Settings for the computer.

By IMPORTing a csv file, one can specify the date format of the incoming data and avoid this problem.

To demonstrate it in the file you provided, change the filtering part of the macro to also pick up text dates.  eg:

```
With fltrRng
    .AutoFilter field:=7, _
    Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria2:=Format(lngStart, """*""/mm/yyyy")

    .AutoFilter field:=8, _
   Criteria1:="<" & lngEnd, _
        Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria2:=Format(lngEnd - 1, """*""/mm/yyyy")

End With
```

However, this is far from ideal because, most likely, even the dates that are rendered as "real Excel dates" were probably translated incorrectly.  In other words, if the CSV file contained `05/01/2019` meaning `5-Jan-2019`, it would be translated to `1-May-2019` in the scenario cited.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for having a look and explaining the process so thoroughly. I've had a go at applying this to my workbook. This VBA only picks up data that fits the dates of May exactly. It's missing out all dates that pass through May 2019 which I need.

Comment: @user11497252 That is due to another problem.  It is actually returning all of the **dates** that are in May.  The lines not showing, that you expect to, are text representations of dates in DMY format.  But they have been rendered as text.  However you are obtaining the dates, you have to correct your process so the dates will be translated correctly.  It may also be that the dates that are "real" dates were translated incorrectly from your source.