# Date variables for filtering passed on to Excell does not get activated correctly

Tags: excel, date, filter, date-format

I'm having an issue with an autofilter based on a date.

The date is selected by a "date picking" function giving the correct date format "dd-mm-yyyy" The date is stored in a variable of type Date. A "Debug.Print" shows the correct date format. A TypeName() also states the variable as Date.

The variable is passed on to the active sheet  "ActiveSheet.Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & BalanceDate, Operator:=xlAnd"

The active sheet has multiple columns, and Field 3 is formatted as "short date" in the format "dd-mm-yyyy".

If a date like "02-12-2019" is passed on to the sheet, the filtering works. If a date like 13-12-2019" is passed on to the sheet, no data is filtered out (all data is removed). The Filter on the colum shows, that the column is filtered, and when selecting  the Excell "Date filter -> User defined filter", the  correct date is shown in the options, and when clicking "OK", the filtering now is applied correctly.

This issue has been haunting me for a long time now, and I've been trying to solve it with declaring the format of the dates but no luck.

Anyone out there with an idea on why this happens?

Im using Excel O365 Danish language

Comment: Look at [How to fix date filter VBA as it is not picking up all dates that fall within my range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127468/how-to-fix-date-filter-vba-as-it-is-not-picking-up-all-dates-that-fall-within-my)

Answer (score 0):

Well thnx a million you saved my day - I've been looking for that answer for quite a while - FINALLY THE SHIT WORKS AS PLANNED :-)

Creating a variable containing the Long value of the date (Clng(BalanceDate)) and the use this to use as criteria did the trick :-)

Comment: Glad to help. I'm going to mark this as a duplicate question, since the other answer was what you needed.